# Do superstitions follow the logic of the empty universe?

Tags: belief

Superstitions are of two kinds, false belief about real onjects ( cat crossed road brings bad luck), or belief about objects that cannot exist (ghosts inhabit places where someone was murdered).

Since they are untrue or undefined, they belong to the empty universe.

Is the set of all superstitions equal to the empty universe ?

Comment: What is the "empty universe"?

Comment: There are many many false beliefs; thus, their collection (if any) is not empty.

Comment: No. Ghosts are objects that *do not* exist (presumably), it does not mean that they *cannot* exist, there is nothing inherently impossible about them. What is untrue in our world can be true in what is called [possible worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possible_world) in modal logic. And they are far from empty. Only few superstitions are self-contradictory, and hence impossible.

Comment: Why not just say that there is nothing self contradictory about the concept of a ghost rather than saying they **can** or **cannot** exist? Existence is usually meant in a metaphysical sense, and not just a logical sense.

Comment: @thinkingman Usually meant by whom? And because logic is broadly shared while metaphysics is to each their own.

Comment: Yes but **existence** is usually talked about within the scope of metaphysics. When one believes that ghosts do not exist, they also believe that it is “impossible” for them to exist. This is ultimately just a semantic issue though so I won’t bother.

Comment: The term 'empty universe' is so ambiguous that you are free to equate it with the set of all superstitions or any other similar nonsense.

Comment: @thinkingman Metaphysics and physics alike. In this [article](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0) (1937) it declares in "modern physics ... only that which is observable is significant", and resolves a realist dilemma between the *physically* unobservable and the *practically* unobservable by treating them the same, hence: "It follows that modern physics is justifiable only in terms of an idealistic philosophy." (i.e. observation makes existence.) So unobserved phenomena may be considered non-existent, but may still be discovered in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Lets begin with examining your assertion that "since they [superstitions] are untrue or undefined, they belong to the empty universe". What does that mean? What is an empty universe? The universe, after all, is not empty.

Well, to make sense of a claim like that, let's say that "a universe" or "a possible universe" is just a possible way that things might have been. We'll ignore the very serious problem of what it means that something might have been and just assume that you and I can have similar intuitions about this so we can discuss possible universes even if we can't rigorously define them. The actual universe is, of course, a possible universe. A merely possible universe is a possible universe that is not the actual universe.

One merely possible universe is the empty universe, by which I assume you mean a universe in which there are no physical objects. Note that there are still beliefs that are true of an empty universe. Once such belief is "the universe is empty".

Now let's talk about what it means for a superstition to "belong" to a universe. A superstition is not a physical object, so it can't belong to a universe in the same sense as a physical object. What kind of object is a superstition? Well, let's say it is a theory, a set of claims or propositions. A theory is the sort of thing that is not present like a physical object in a universe, but it can be true in a universe or false in a universe. In philosophy we say that a theory that is false in some universes and true in others is "contingent".

So a superstition is a contingent theory that happens to be false in the actual universe. Is the superstition true in the empty universe? Well, think about it. If a superstition about ghosts is false in the actual universe because ghosts don't exist, then wouldn't it be equally false in the empty universe where ghosts don't exist? In fact, in the empty universe, the superstition about black cats would be in the same category as the superstition about ghosts: they would both be about things that don't exist, and so equally false.

What you may be trying to get at is not the empty universe, but the empty set of possible universes. What is a set of universes? There is a possible universe where cars were not invented but planes were, a possible universe where planes were not invented and cars were, a possible universe where neither was invented, and a possible universe (the actual universe) where both were invented. This is a set of four possible universes.

What I think you may be trying to get at is the idea that superstitions are true in no possible universe; that is, they are true in a set of universes that is empty. Is that the case? Well, there is a possible universe where ghosts are real so theories about ghosts can be true.

Do you disagree with that claim? Well, then it looks like we do have to discuss "a possible way that things might have been" after all. For me (and most philosophers)  the laws of nature might have been different. There might have been no gravity or no electromagnetic force. All elements might have been made up of fire, water, air, and earth. And there might have been ghosts.

But you can disagree with this (and some philosophers) do. You might take the laws of nature as given. You might say that a possible universe is one that is physically possible, a universe where the initial conditions might have been different, but the laws of nature as they exist in the actual universe are the only possible way the universe might have been. In that case, you would be right that superstitions are true in the empty set of universes.

So if we change your question "is the set of all superstitions equal to the empty universe?" to the question "Is the set of physically possible universes in which superstitions are true equal to the empty set of physically possible universes?", the answer is "Arguably yes".

Answer (score 0):

Per your definitions I would have to say **yes**.

1. False beliefs correspond to *nothing* (empty) in reality.
2. Nonexistent things have an *empty* extension. You may point to *nothing* and say, "this is a ghost".

If the *empty universe* can be rephrased, *salva veritate*, as *the empty set*, you *are* correct, mon ami!